# How to use parameters in QuTiP?

Tags: programming, qutip, quantum-optics

I am working with QuTiP to do some calculations based on my proposed Hamiltonian. The Hamiltonian of my system has some coupling constants that show the strength of coupling between matter and light(Suppose the Jaynes-Cummings Model).

I have in mind to not specify any initial value to those parameters and let them be shown in my final results. Simply speaking, I do not want to obtain numeric results. Instead, I want to have the exact derivation of the result based on parameters. I know that we can do this in Matlab using syms to set variables. However is there any piece of code that I can use to use QuTiP instead of Matlab?